# error: `TFD_NONBLOCK' undeclared (first use in this function)

Tags: c, linux

I am using timerfd mechanism, and getting this error on compilation:  `error:`TFD_NONBLOCK' undeclared (first use in this function)`

How to resolve?

Here is the statement:
`timer_fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, TFD_NONBLOCK);`

Looks like timerfd support is missing from libc. sys/timerfd.h is absent. Any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `timerfd_create()`, you need to run Linux 2.6.25 (or higher) with glibc 2.8 (or higher).

Comment: sorry mine is old one. 2.6.9. is there any way to update this via yum or anything similar?

Comment: Indeed, I would suggest an upgrade. My own glibc (reasonably up to date) is `2.12.2`. `2.6.9` seems *old* :)